# What is "[DIR]" in the VS Code ftp-simple extension? Why is this happening?

Tags: visual-studio-code

gI wanted to open a directory from FTP with VS Code for various customizations. I used the ftp-simple extension for this. However, some subfolders appear as [DIR]. What is the meaning of this?

I thought it was a placeholder because they are being processed, my internet connection is very fast and I think this process should be completed very fast. So I searched for a way to check it.

I activated the Panel (View > Appearance > Panel) then selected ftp-simple from the OUTPUT tab. A lot of downloads were done, but the indexing process was not in progress for the folders that appeared as [DIR] and their contents. When I took no action, there was no indication that the upload was in progress.

How can I ensure that everything is fully installed?

My goal is to open and instantly make edits on VS Code on a site under construction.

A few screenshots;

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a placeholder for directories that have not yet been loaded, and which can be loaded by clicking them. [From the docs](https://github.com/humy2833/FTP-Simple#remote-configoption):

> **ftp-simple.remote-workspace-load-all** - *boolean* - (option) Indicates whether all files are loaded during initial run. If false, the sub folder ([DIR]) will load when it is clicked. **Default:** true

That's a performance optimization (reduces initial network load / "lazy loading"). If you want everything loaded at the very beginning, set `ftp-simple.remote-workspace-load-all`, since the default is `true`, you should find the line in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson) where you set it to `false` and remove that line.

You can find related source code here: https://github.com/humy2833/FTP-Simple/blob/master/extension.js.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to VS Code, I couldn't find these settings.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it appropriate to post an update for those who will reach this question later, there are some developments;

Instead, I now use the SFTP plugin developed by Natizyskunk. It works much better and smoother, I recommend it

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Natizyskunk.sftp

Comment: this doesn't actually answer the question: "What is "[DIR]" in the VS Code ftp-simple extension? Why is this happening?"

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is unclear why I did not explain why I suggested this plugin as a solution.

1- The plugin I have problems with doesn't download files and folders, it creates a copy of their names and calls it [DIR]. When you go into that folder or open the file to take action, the download happens, but when there are too many of them, it is difficult to take action, or even, as I experienced, it gets blocked and doesn't work. You have to start all over again, which creates problems in the workflow. This was the structure of the plugin and it was not possible to change it.

Comment: 2- So I found a different plugin and wanted to share it. The alternative plugin I mentioned doesn't do this. It connects to FTP and the user downloads the section they want to process, processes it and uploads it when finished. The recordings are local, but that's not a problem since it's easy to upload.